# JAXB ClassNotFoundException com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory when hot-deploying camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, liferay, wildfly

Yes I know, there are numerous questions and answers since JAXB was removed from JDK 11. But this one is specific.

I've a Wildfly Server (tested with 18.0.1 and 16.0.0) running with the wildfly-camel subsystem 11.0.1 patch applied. The patch installs Camel 2.25.0

Deploying and Hot-Deploying (while the server is up) Camel routes works fine! 
**Until I deploy Liferay on the same server :-(**

Then the Hot-Deploy of a camel route gives me the annoying

```
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory from [Module "org.apache.camel.spring" version 2.25.0...
```

exeption.

**No matter if I run the server on JDK 11 or JDK 8!** Liferay 7.3.2 claims to be runnable on both JDK versions so I guess it has something to with the way Liferay was build. 
Reading this article
http://www.descher.at/descher-vu/2019/01/java-11-jaxb-and-osgi/
that the JAXB topic is very complex and far from being resolved.

**Question**: 
How can a deployed application destroy otherwise working classpath resolutions?
And more important:
How to fix it?

I tried removing the 2 jars in question *jaxb-api.jar* and *jaxb-impl.jar* from Liferay. But that didn't help.

Comment: do you mean: Once you deploy Liferay, your non-Liferay applications fail to work, even though they did before? Or you get everything working, just not Liferay?

Comment: wildfly-camel is working. Hot-Deploy is working. When I deploy Liferay, Hot-Deploy breaks with the error I described.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the root cause of the error is a missing dependency to *com.sun.xml.bind* in the *org.apache.camel.spring* module of the wildfly-camel patch.

I filed [the issue in detail](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/issues/2964).

Looks like Liferay has nothing to do with it. Because in theory jboss-modules should separate the deployments.